# How can I create SQL Server Geography polygons that are of a specific size?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, geography

I want to create a group of polygons for a city that are 80km x 80km.  Given a starting Lat and Long, my thought is I can add 80km to that point so that I get 4 points to create the polygon.

(x,y) -> (x+80km, y) -> (x+80km, y+80km) -> (x, y+80km) -> (x,y)

Where I'm having difficulty is finding a way to calculate the point +80km.  I've found the [SQL Server Spatial Tools](http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/) and there is a function

```
SqlGeography LocateAlongGeog(SqlGeography g, double distance)
```

But so far I haven't been able to figure out how to use it.  I will continue to play with this but if there are any other approaches I can take, or if anyone knows how to properly use this function, I'd be grateful.

Comment: I have done similar things for radius searches, but it is far from trivial. We implemented the Haversine formula in T-SQL, for which there are some workarounds. Nowadays, you could do this with CLR stored procedures. Anyhow, this is not easy because a degree of longitude is smaller as you move toward the poles. Good luck.

Comment: this might help http://www.zodiacal.com/tools/lat_table.php

Comment: @deathApril - thanks for the link.  It's interesting that the distance is the same regardless if you go north or south from the equator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Longitude is a "great circle" measure, i.e. if you draw a circle representing a particular longitude round the Earth, it's always a circle whose centre is the centre of the Earth - so to circumnavigate the Earth at a constant longitude, you always travel the same distance:

```
2 * PI * 6378 /* 6378 is the radius of the Earth in km */
```

So, moving North (i.e travelling along the same longitude) 80 km will increase your latitude by:

```
360 * 80 / (2 * PI * 6378)
```

Latitude is trickier cos the distance travelled when you circumnavigate the Earth at the same latitude changes depending on the latitude at which you're travelling: however, the formula is simple and I looked it up at: http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/askasci/env99/env086.htm

```
2 * PI * 6378 * COS(LAT)   /* where LAT is your Latitude */
```

So, if you are at latitude LAT, and move 80km East, you will increase your longitude by:

```
360 * 80 / (2 * PI * 6378 * COS(LAT))
```

Couple of things to note:
a) 6378 is only accurate to the nearest km
b) The East/West between your two Northerly points will not be precisely 80km - not significantly different for Latitudes between about 80 degrees North and 80 degrees South - as long as you're not looking for high-precision pinpoint accuracy (which I'm guessing with base measurements of 80 km you're not) it'll do just nicely (and point nicelt at Bing or Google, say)
c) SQL calculates trigonometry functions using radians not degrees - so in SQL your cosine will need to be:
    COS(PI * LAT / 180)

HTH and makes some sort of sense

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this.  Thanks for the input.